# knockout.js is there a way to set value binding to newly created element in bindingHandler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm creating bindingHandler which suppose to create `label` and `input` elements inside of the element and attach newly created input value to observable already setted in the viewModel.

but this is trickier than I thought, I can't figure out how can I pass observable, because anything I tried either throws an error or binds observable function as a string, which is not what I want.

So I wonder how can I achieve this result?

Currently I'm passing values like this

```
data-bind="input: {placeholder: 'Username', value: username, class: 'input'}"
```

I know I could achieve similar results by creating a template, but I wonder if there is a way to things like that? It would give me much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout exposes a function `ko.applyBindingsToNode` that does what you need. After creating the `input` element, you should set up the binding like this:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, function() {
    return {
        value: valueAccessor().value
    };
});
```

Since version 3.0 of Knockout, you can use this method also:

```
ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(input, {
    value: function() {
        return valueAccessor().value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I added this code to one of my bindings. It's throwing the following error:
`Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "datepicker: function (){return datePrepared }"`
`Message: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return b()[c]}"`
`Message: Browser doesn't support addEventListener or attachEvent`
(Context info: My custom binding creates a datepicker field with an `input` element.)

Comment: The `input` parameter must be an `DOMElement`. You must be passing in something else.